# Can the particle か have an exhortative value?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-か

> 開戦といきますか！

Judging from the exclamation mark and from the context (a battle immediately starts after the commander of an army says this), I think that in the sentence above か could have an exhortative value. Is it correct? If so, is it a common thing or only a manga/anime thing? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am going to say yes here even though "exhortative" may slightly be too strong a word for it.

The sentence-final 「か」 can certainly express inducement, solicitation, invitation, etc. and it is widely used in real life, not just in manga/anime.

The exclamation mark, however, is completely optional.  It is just used more often in manga than in real life for the majority of native speakers.

> "Let's start a war!"
>
> "Let's go to a war!"

The final 「か」 adds a "**shall we?**" kind of nuance to the statement.